# Executing VBSCript in COM dll using .Net and Interop

Tags: .net, interop, vbscript

I have a VB6 application that I am converting to .Net in phases.  The current phase requires .net to make a call to a VB6 dll through interop to execute VBScript using the MS Script control. Other than the process being "convoluted" are there any known issues with this setup?  Sometimes nothing is executed or I get an error "Attempted to read or write protected memory". However, if I call the same method using a VB6 app the VBScript executes as expected.

Thoughts?

Comment: why would you use such a twisted way? what is it that vbscript file does that VB6 or .net can't do? Code please?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: In the past we would use the Scripting host to allow clients to create and execute custom logic within in the context of the application.  This is fairly straight-forward to achieve in .NET but as the OP points out the current task is piecemeal port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what could be causing your specific problem, but have you looked at the Interop Forms Toolkit?

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb419144.aspx

It makes communication between .NET and VB 6.0 really easy.

These Codeproject articles have been useful to me in the past:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/VB6InteropToolkit2.aspx?fid=422404&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2230658

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/VB6_-_C__Interop_Form.aspx